# FLEX: how to correctly pass the link to a page?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using

```
<mx:LinkButton label="www.google.com" click="navigateToURL(new URLRequest(event.currentTarget.label.toString()))" />
```

to open a browser window to display the website on the label of my LinkButton. However I cannot correctly pass the link.. you see the problem:

```
file://localhost/..myapp/bin-debug/www.google.com
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you didn't add "http://" to the beginning. Most browsers can adjust for that because they're built to assume you mean http:// if you leave it out - but Flash Player won't adjust for that, since in theory you could be referring to a file on your hard drive or whatever.

Either add the http:// to your label or to your URLRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that the text is something like "google.com" rather than an absolute url.

Try this:

```
<mx:LinkButton label="www.google.com" click="navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://' + event.currentTarget.label.toString()))" />
```

Comment: sorry I've accidentally removed it. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when defining links there are three ways they will be interpreted:

- `xy/file.ext` is a relative reference using the current folder as the starting point. It is equivalent to `./xy/file.ext` in that way.
  So when you are at `http://example.com/subdirectory/index.html`, it get's interpreted as `http://example.com/subdirectory/xy/file.ext`.
- `/xy/file.ext` is a relative reference using the host's root as the starting point.
  So in the above situation the link would lead to `http://example.com/xy/file.ext`.
- The other method is by specifying an absolute link. This is the solution you should use to navigate to a different host, so especially in your case where you want to link to google. Simply specify the full host with the protocol: `http://google.com` as the link target and it will work.